# Must solution of the differential equation $\frac{dy}{dx}=f(x,y)$ and $ y(x_0)=y_0$ be unique?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Must solution of the differential equation $\displaystyle\frac{dy}{dx}=f(x,y)$ and $\displaystyle y(x_0)=y_0$ be unique?

Example: I found that (i) $y=x,x\neq0$, (ii) $y=|x|$ and (iii)  $f(x)= \begin {cases} x&\text{if }x >0\\
-Ax\ &\text{if }x<0 \end {cases}$ for any $A\neq 0$ all satistify the differential equation $\displaystyle\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{y}{x}$ and $\displaystyle y(1)=1$. Can we accept them as answer?

On the other hand, if we start from $\displaystyle\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{y}{x}$, it leads to $\displaystyle\int_1^{y}\frac{dy}{y}=\int_1^{x}\frac{dx}{x}$. To apply the [First Fundamental theorem of calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus), $x,y>0$ so that $\frac{1}{x}$ and $\frac{1}{y}$ are continuous at $[1,x]$ and $[1,y]$ respectively. Solve it and we get $y=x,x>0$.

Any comment or answer?

Answer (score 1):

No the solution is not unique in general, if the right hand side is local lipschitz the solution will be unique with picard lindelöf, if the right hand side is continuous a solution exists (but not necessary a unique one).

Without thinking a lot 
$$\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
y'=y^{\frac{1}{3}}\\
y(0)=0\\
\end{array}
\right.$$ 
has at least 2 different solutions, something like 
$$y(t)=\frac{2}{3} \cdot \sqrt{\frac{2}{3}} t^\frac{3}{2}$$
and the trivial solution $y(t)=0$